# Attach client certificate to web service call based on stubs created with wsdl2java

Tags: java, web-services, certificate

I have created the stub classes for consuming the web service with wsdl2java but I need to specify a client certificate for the transport. How do I do this?

In .NET I am used to be able to directly attach a X509Certificate object to similar stub classes before making the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, you have a couple options:

- Specify the `java.net.ssl*` parameters to setup a cert store, password, etc.  You'll want to use `keytool` to set up these objects.

Here's the code, or these can be specified on the command line with -D.  Note that these will be global to your app.

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "myKeyStore.p12");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "pkcs12");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password");
```

- Create a custom `SSLFactory` which configures your certs at a lower level and set it on your WS context.  You can [google](http://www.google.com?q=jaxws+ssl+client+certs) for this and find lots of info out there.  Also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689233/pass-client-certificate-to-web-service-without-setting-system-wide-properties) (the author says it's for JAX-RPC, but in the comments he changes his impl to JAX-WS).

You can find more info in the [JSSE docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Customization) (this for java 1.5).

Comment: Excellent, those three lines was all it took.